# Remove page number on chapter page

Tags: numbering, chapters

What I am looking for is to have the chapter initial page without a page number.
Apparently Latex or/and `\pagestyle{fancy}` use `\pagestyle{plain}` by default on the footer.

So, I proceded to modify the footer like that:
`\fancyfoot{}`

This working, but it is not on the chapter initial page.

The solution looks like to be:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
...
\chapter{My chapter}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Chapter text here...
```

But this means I'll have to type `\pagestyle{fancy}` everytime I make a new chapter. Is there any way to optimize that?

I tried:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{\oldchapter\pagestyle{empty}}
```

But I got the following error: `! Argument of \thispagestyle has an extra }.`

I also tried:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\emptypagestyle{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\def\chapter{\cleardoublepage\oldchapter\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

But no luck either: `! Paragraph ended before \l@chapter was complete. ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [...]`

Comment: You can have it easily with `titlesec`.

Comment: `\oldchapter\pagestyle` means you are passing `\pagestyle` as the argument to the original `\chapter` command, after that things go wrong. you need to declare your new command with arguments then do something like `\oldchapter[#1]{#2}\pagestyle{empty}` but simpler would be to use fancyhdr to redefine the plain style not to have a number

Comment: Maybe try `\apptocmd{\chapter]{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}` from the `etoolbox` package`.

Comment: @Bernard No, it can't work, it would be essentially the same as the `\oldchapter` way. The final part of `\chapter` is code for deciding whether the next token is `*`; with your patch the next token would be `\thispagestyle`.

Comment: I see. So if he wants to have it done automatically, a solution will be in `titlesec`. Not sure the ‘soft’ version will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't use the `plain` pagestyle anywhere else, just add

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
}
```

in the preamble.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}

Chapter text here...

\end{document}
```

If you need the `plain` page style in other places of the document, define a new one and patch `\chapter` to use it.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{chapterstart}{}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}

Chapter text here...

\end{document}
```